# Printer used to work, not anymore?

Tags: printer, hp

I have an older HP8600 All-in-One-Printer which has always worked great. For some reason it is no longer working. Having trouble connecting to my WiFi I think.

It’ll say I am connected but when I try to AirPrint it will say I’m not connected. I’m not sure if it has anything to do with Bluetooth.

I read somewhere that my printer is not Bluetooth compatible. If that’s true, then why was it working before no problem??

Comment: I have an HP 8610 that supports TCP/IP Wireless - not Bluetooth. Can you connect with regular wireless.  Air Print for me works that way.

Comment: No, your printer has no Bluetooth as expected. Why it doesn't work now, who knows? You need to troubleshoot. It can be a simple misconfiguration on the network or it can be defective. Start by confirming it's actually connected - check the router if you must -, otherwise reboot everything and try again. Check your clients (devices that print to the printer) a look for IP mismatches, etc.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details: What OS are you using to try to connect to the printer? Windows? macOS? Linux?

Comment: what is the title question asking?

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 things that may resolve the problem.

First, as only AirPrint fails, try setting the iPhone/iPad's proxy to Auto, as [shown here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Mobile-Printing-Cloud-Printing/airprint-does-not-find-my-officejet-pro-8600/td-p/1137677).

> Go to settings on your iPad. Select wifi.  Press the blue arrow next to the network name in the list your printer is currently on.  When the network settings page comes up, make sure the http proxy setting is set to auto.  This solved the same issue I had with the 8600 printer.  Hope this helps!

If you use a Mac, go to System Settings > Network > WiFi

If that does not work, try resetting the printer to factory defaults, as [shown here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printing-Errors-or-Lights-Stuck-Print-Jobs/HOW-DO-I-RESET-OFFICEJET-PRO-8600-TO-FACTORY-SETTINGS/td-p/1421749).

> **Performing a reset**
>
> Follow these steps to perform a reset of the product.
>
> 1. Press the Power button ( ) to turn on the product.
> 2. **With the product turned on**, disconnect the power cord from the rear of the product.
> 3. Unplug the power cord from the wall outlet.
>    Wait at least 15 seconds.
> 4. Plug the power cord back into the wall outlet.
> 5. Reconnect the power cord to the rear of the product.
> 6. If the product does not turn on by itself, press the Power button ( ) to turn it on.

Comment: I went ahead and added pertinent info to the question. Otherwise this would have been a “link only answer,” which is discouraged here since links ca go away and not work over time. If you feel this is incorrect, please feel free to edit.